# Textview onclick open keyboard and set the input as Textview's text

Tags: android, keyboard, textview, settext

I am trying to click on textview and open keyboard (i did that) and then what the user inputs i want to set that text in particular text view. I am using Fragments.

Getting keyboard by:

```
TextView test = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtSent);

    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            InputMethodManager imgr = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imgr.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
        }// end onClick
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow exactly what you're asking but have you considered using EditText instead of TextView? I believe EditText will be easier to work with.

Answer (score 2):

set android:editable="true".  Although you're better off with an EditText.